# Why is my cfoutput not showing the right result per year?

Tags: coldfusion, cfml

I'm having trouble figuring the logic on how I can output this information.

Basically, I'm querying a yearly report from my database where some donors post as **"Anonymous"** per year. Problem is, once they give anonymously at any given year, their name stops showing up, and appears as **"Anonymous"** for the following years, including the previous years as well.

The list should only list **"Anonymous"** for the current year that it is pulling the information from, if they have given anonymously for that year. Otherwise, it should just show their name.

SalAnnRep_Ovr would be the field where **Anonymous** would show in our Database.

Otherwise, it would link to their name at SalAnnRep, if it is **null**.

I am not sure if I need to set the years as a loop and then set an `<cfif>/<cfelse>` statement. Any help would be appreciated!

This is my code where I set the `cfif` statement:

```
<td><cfif SalAnnRep_Ovr IS NOT "">#SalAnnRep_Ovr#<cfelse>#SalAnnRep#</cfif></td>
```

The data that I am pulling from my DB:

```
    <cfquery datasource="gnConstituents" name="GetCon">
SELECT IDCon, Ca_First, Ca_Middle, Ca_Last, Ca_Suffix, isSchoolChampion,
<cfif FYoffset LTE 5>FY#FYoffset#_CY AS CY<cfelse>0 AS CY</cfif>, SalAnnRep,
SalAnnRep_Ovr
FROM Constituents
WHERE RecordType = 'Ind'
</cfquery>
```

I am also retrieving the year through roman numeral.

```
<cfquery datasource="prep" name="GetAGC"> 
SELECT *
FROM romans
WHERE RomNum = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#Form.AGC#">
ORDER BY RomNum DESC
</cfquery>
```

Comment: So... How does anonymous come into the picture here? If they're anonymous, the `SalAnnRep_Ovr` column contains 'Anonymous'? what sets that column?

Comment: Thank you for catching that, I clarified it in the original post:
SalAnnRep_Ovr would be the field where Anonymous would show in our Database.

Otherwise, it would link to their name at SalAnnRep, if it is null.

Comment: In that case... does the donor get a new record with each donation? or are you just updating the existing one. If it's just updating the existing one, are you sure it isn't also updating all the others?

Comment: It would just update the donor as 'Anonymous' if it is Anonymous.
It flags the donation type as Anonymous, but it does not create a new record.

Comment: yeah... so... how can you then determine which previous donations were not anonymous, if the user is marked as anonymous in general? If you want the anonymous flag to be per donation, marking it on the user record rather than the donation record doesn't make much sense.

Comment: What version of CF?

Comment: And what version and flavor of SQL? This sounds more like a SQL problem than a CF one.

Comment: And what data type is this `SalAnnRep_Ovr` column? Can you provide some example data to make it clearer?